# How can I use the Stack Exchange API for creating a site like Stack Overflow in another language?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stackapps, clone

How can I use the Stack Exchange API for creating a site like Stack Overflow in another language?

I know there are similar questions but no clear answer. It says in the banner (ads) "use our API to build your own q&a platform". But how? I have looked at Stack Apps and Stack Exchange but couldn't find anything.

So for free or not can I create a site like Stack Overflow of my own? If yes how?

Note: I don't have to run it on my hardware.

And what has Stack Apps to do with this?

Comment: see http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot. The API is for interacting with the existing sites. See area51 if you want to propose a new one.